# Oracle query works in SQL+ but returns no rows in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datetime

Help, any ideas??

I am using the OLEDB adapter (Oracle OLEDB) with Oracle 10.2.0.3.0.  My code generates the SQL for the query, then when I execute it into an OLEDBDataReader, the HasRows is False.  However, if I output the contents of the query string, copy, and paste into SQL+ (logged in as the same user from the same client machine), it returns 993 rows.  What gives??

Here's a segment of my code:

```
Dim DB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("{0};Password={1}", ConnectionString, DBPassword))
Dim flowQuerySQL As String
'... code to generate query
Debug.Print(flowQuerySQL)
Dim flowQueryCMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(flowQuerySQL, DB)
Dim flowQuery As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = flowQueryCMD.ExecuteReader()
While flowQuery.HasRows
    '...handle rows
End While
```

The debug.print statement shows:

```
SELECT CLASS_ID, OBJECT_ID FROM TDM_SF_PROCESS WHERE CLASS_ID=853 AND TDM_END_TIME >= '01-Jan-2009' AND TDM_END_TIME < '31-May-2009' AND TDM_STATUS <> 1 AND TDM_STATUS <> 2
```

Comment: Is there only one result?  Which you're consuming and now HasRows is false?

Comment: Note the next statement after executing the command is `While flowQuery.HasRows`.  However, I just tried removing the dates from the query, and now `HasRows` is `True`.  Why is that?  Is there something about OleDb that requires the dates in a different format from what Oracle wants?  I tried dates & times, but that gave me ORA-01861.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just recently started working VB.NET against Oracle, and dates are tempermental.

This approach has worked for me so far:

```
SELECT CLASS_ID, OBJECT_ID 
FROM TDM_SF_PROCESS 
WHERE CLASS_ID=853 
  AND TDM_END_TIME >= TO_DATE('01-Jan-2009', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
  AND TDM_END_TIME < TO_DATE('31-May-2009', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
  AND TDM_STATUS <> 1 
  AND TDM_STATUS <> 2
```

It wouldn't work until I used the "TO_DATE" function.  Hopefully this will work for you, too.

I'm a MS-SQL guy, so I haven't been able to research the "why" of why this works, yet.  Enlightenment, anyone?

Comment: +1 duh, after reviewing some of my old code, I too am using TO_DATE.  For some reason the strings don't parse correctly unless they're in the Oracle system format.  Infact I use this: to_date('10/24/2011','mm/dd/yyyy') and even have it as an AutoHotKey.

Comment: Darn, I thought that would go!  Here's the SQL it executes:  `SELECT CLASS_ID, OBJECT_ID, TDM_END_TIME FROM TDM_SF_PROCESS WHERE CLASS_ID=862 AND TDM_END_TIME >= TO_DATE('1-Jan-2009', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') AND TDM_END_TIME < TO_DATE('31-May-2009', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') AND TDM_STATUS <> 1 AND TDM_STATUS <> 2`  Still HasRows=False

Comment: Disregard that!  Class ID 862 has no rows.  853, looks like it worked.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked.  I also updated my example for 4-digit years.  I (later) realized that I had lifted my example from an implementation that had specifically called for 2-digit years (ugh!).

Comment: Data problems are always the last to be checked :D

Comment: From what I remember this is an OLEDB/ODBC convention and the actual OLEDB driver won't convert to date unless its inside #31-May-2009#.  So the driver tells the DB that it's characters not date.

Comment: Wow.  I had always thought the #31-May-2009# was an MS Access holdover.  I had not even thought it could be a driver convention.  I'm going to go try that out.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you building a query that does not use bind variables?  Or are you manually filling in the bind variables in your debug output for us?  If you are not using bind variables, you're realistically going to create a massive performance problem in your database because you're going to crush Oracle's shared pool.  You're going to create insecure code that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  And you are going to end up spending a lot of time dealing with gotchas relating to data types, escaping strings, etc..

If you were using bind variables, you would simply create local date variables in your VB.Net application, bind them to your query, and everything would generally work.  This would be much more efficient since Oracle would only need to do a hard parse on the statement once and wouldn't flood the shared pool with similar statements when you run the query again and again with different dates.

I am by not a VB developer.  But if you're using bind variables, you would replace the literals in your SQL statement with placeholders, i.e.

```
AND TDM_END_TIME >= :early_time 
AND TDM_END_TIME <  :late_time 
AND TDM_STATUS <> :status_1 
AND TDM_STATUS <> :status_2
```

You would then provide values for those bind variables at runtime, i.e.

```
flowQueryCMD.Parameters.Add( ":early_time", <<your VB date object>> )
flowQueryCMD.Parameters.Add( ":late_time", <<your VB date object>> )
```

Finally, you execute the query

2) If you are not using bind variables, then you have to make sure that your data types match.  '01-Jan-2009' is a string, not a date, so Oracle has to implicitly convert the string to a date.  It does this by using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` happens not to be 'DD-MON-YYYY', the conversion will fail (or silently do something unexpected) and you won't get the results you expect.  Since the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` can be different for every session, you never want to rely on any particular `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` being set in any particular session otherwise your code may work for you and fail for your colleague who happens to prefer European date formats.  Your code may work fine in one session (say, SQL*Plus, that is getting its `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` from one place) and not in another session (say, a .Net application that gets it's language, character set, and date format settings from the .Net stack)

There are a couple of ways to specify date literals in Oracle.  The first is to use the ANSI date literal (or timestamp literal) syntax (note that ANSI date literals are always specified as YYYY-MM-DD)

```
AND tdm_end_time >= date '2009-01-01'
AND tdm_end_time <  date '2009-05-31'
```

The second option is to do an explicit conversion yourself using the `TO_DATE` funciton

```
AND tdm_end_time >= to_date( '01-Jan-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
AND tdm_end_time <  to_date( '31-May-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
```

Comment: +1 for the detail.  Being new to Oracle and its terminology:  Can you post an example w/ Bind Variables, please?